# Single selection for a check box in grid view column

Tags: html, angular

I have a grid view and the last column contains a checkbox. I need to restrict it to a single selection (only one row can be selected).

```html
<tr *ngFor="let permit of PermitDetails" (click)="GoByClick(permit)">
  <td style="text-align: center">{{permit.TVA_BATCH_APP_NO}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center">{{permit.TVA_PA_OBD_COMP_NAME}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center">{{permit.TVA_PA_OBD_COMP_CODE}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center">
    <input type="checkbox" [value]="permit.TA_PA_IS_CHECK" [checked]="permit.TA_PA_IS_CHECK" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event.target.checked ? permit.TA_PA_IS_CHECK = true : permit.TA_PA_IS_CHECK = false">
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Each time you select a row, just unselect the previous one by setting its `TA_PA_IS_CHECK` property to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (assuming that TVA_BATCH_APP_NO can be used as unique identifier) :

```
<tr *ngFor="let permit of PermitDetails" (click)="GoByClick(permit)">
  <td style="text-align: center">{{permit.TVA_BATCH_APP_NO}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center">{{permit.TVA_PA_OBD_COMP_NAME}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center">{{permit.TVA_PA_OBD_COMP_CODE}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center">
    <input type="checkbox" [value]="permit.TA_PA_IS_CHECK" [checked]="permit.TA_PA_IS_CHECK" (change)="checkOne(permit.TVA_BATCH_APP_NO)">
  </td> 
</tr>
```

And in your controller:

```
checkOne(permitId){
   for(var i=0;i<this.PermitDetails.length;i++){
      this.PermitDetails[i].TA_PA_IS_CHECK = (permits[i].TVA_BATCH_APP_NO == permitId)
   }
}
```